# date string doesnt work

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I have the following code:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
def get_data( date )
  date_string = date.strftime('%d-%m-%y')
  url = "http://mobile.bahn.de/bin/mobil/bhftafel.exe/dox?input=Richard-Strauss-Stra%DFe%2C+M%FCnchen%23625127&date={date_string}&time=20%3A41&productsFilter=1111111111000000&REQTrain_name=&maxJourneys=10&start=Suchen&boardType=Abfahrt&ao=yes"
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
  doc.xpath('//div//p').remove
doc = doc.xpath('//div').each do |node|
   text = node.text.gsub(/\n([ \t]*\n)+/,"\n").gsub(/^\s+|\s+$/,'')
   puts text unless text.empty?
end
```

but I get an error:

> Error: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting keyword_end

Did I forget anything?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need another `end`. Perhaps this

```
def get_data( date )
  date_string = date.strftime('%d-%m-%y')
  url = "http://mobile.bahn.de/bin/mobil/bhftafel.exe/dox?input=Richard-Strauss-Stra%DFe%2C+M%FCnchen%23625127&date={date_string}&time=20%3A41&productsFilter=1111111111000000&REQTrain_name=&maxJourneys=10&start=Suchen&boardType=Abfahrt&ao=yes"
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
  doc.xpath('//div//p').remove
  doc = doc.xpath('//div').each do |node|
     text = node.text.gsub(/\n([ \t]*\n)+/,"\n").gsub(/^\s+|\s+$/,'')
     puts text unless text.empty?
  end
end
```

Comment: Also, `&date={date_string}` needs to be `&date=#{date_string}`

Answer (score 0):

You should fix the indentation of your code. You would notice that the final `end` is closing the `do`, so you should add another `end` closing the method.